# Xamarin deploy to iPhone directly from Visual Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

The docs from Xamarin aren't explicit as to where an iOS device needs to be attached.  I'm using VS to build a Xamarin app through a remote Mac Builder (connected via VPN) but my iphone is attached to my PC with Visual Studio.  Its completely unclear as to whether or not you can deploy a compiled to from the PC you're running Visual Studio on or whether the iOS device needs to be USB'd to the remote Mac running the build.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your iPhone needs to be connected to the OS-X Host:

[image]

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/